# How to do multiple inheritance correctly in C++ using template classes?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, template-classes

I have this derived class:

```
class Chart : public AsposeObjectWrapper<IChart>, public Shape, public Php::Base
    {
        public:
            Chart(System::SharedPtr<IChart> shape) : AsposeObjectWrapper<IChart>(shape), Shape(shape) {};
    }
```

And this base class:

```
class Shape : public AsposeObjectWrapper<IShape>, public Php::Base
{
    public:
        Shape(System::SharedPtr<IShape> shape) : AsposeObjectWrapper<IShape>(shape) {};
```

I can't make the inheritance work for several reasons.

1: the Shape constructor expects IShape pointer argument, while the Chart constructor receives only IChart (which is a subclass of IShape). Is it possible to convert IChart to IShape here:

```
 Chart(System::SharedPtr<IChart> shape) : AsposeObjectWrapper<IChart>(shape), Shape(shape) {};
```

2: Both Chart and Shape inherit from Php::Base, which is now ambiguous. However, I remove it from Chart class, it just won't work. Compiler will complain about stuff coming from that class.
So Shape already has Php::Base as base class. Then Chart (derived from Shape) should just inherit all Php::Base functionality, right?

I'm a bit confused, don't know how to make this work. Basically, all I want is to make Chart inherit from Shape. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: "How to do multiple inheritance [...] ?" don't do multiple inheritance (unless you really really have to)

Comment: Well, that's not really possible in this case. I can't avoid it.

Comment: Virtual inheritance might be the key to solve this, but I am not sure. https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html However, I agree with Cedric that this looks very messy. I think a class redesign might be helpful as well.

Comment: This looks pretty messy... I'd try to avoid multiple inheritance whenever possible. But to the points... 1. It is possible, yes, but you should ideally pass a base class pointer (i.e. IShape) pointing to a derived class object.
2. Yes, you need to remove the direct inheritence in IChart, and it will get access to Php::Base. I don't know what "Compiler will complain about stuff coming from that class. " means.

Comment: virtual inheritance solve the diamond problem, but like already pointed out it seems very messy.